# Can you mount an ext2 image with FUSE as the middleground?

Tags: files, filesystems, mount, fuse

Normally I would mount this image directly to `/mnt/foo`, but I want to do some specific actions if a specific process does read/write/etc on the mount directory.

So I'd like to use FUSE, but I'm not sure if FUSE can work with disk images.

Comment: Use a loopback device to make your image file into a block device. `man 4 loop` and `man losetup` for more info.